# Rails, Getting Started, showing comments partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working through the Getting Started Rails Guide.  Prior to refactoring (Section 7) my comments were displaying.

After refactoring I am getting the following error on my show comments link:

NoMethodError in ArticlesController#show

undefined method `article' for #

Thank you for your time and help.

articles_controller.rb:

```html
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end



private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

comments_controller.rb:

```html
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end
```

views/articles/show.html.erb:

```html
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @article.comments %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render "comments/form" %>

<%= link_to 'Edit Article', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back to Articles', articles_path %>
```

```html
<h1>Listing articles</h1>
<%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %>

<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Text</th>
    </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
                    method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    x</tr>
  <% end %>

</table>
```

views/articles/_form.html.erb:

```html
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this article from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

views/comments/_comment.html.erb

```html
<p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

views/comments/_form.html.erb

```html
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

```html
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

```html
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :articles

end
```

Comment: can you post the complete backtrace? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship name is different from what you have used everywhere else.

Make this change in your model comment.rb

```
belongs_to :article  # Note: article is singular
```